# How to show a cover and place it on a particular position?

Tags: jquery, html, css

There is a html table populated dynamically from ajax : ( here is a very simple capture )

[image]

When I click a cell of the table , apart from the headers c1 through c4 , then I want to show a cover hiding the cells at the left side of the clicked cell : ( here is a very simple capture I made manually from paint )

[image]

In this example I clicked a cell in the column c3. So how to show the cover ?

Comment: What do you mean by cover?

Comment: an object which will hide region of the document.

Comment: It would be great if you could accept the answer of your choice

Comment: in fact the problem was not about styling the table but showing a div having an absolute position with dark background.

Comment: @pheromix The `div` wasn't mentioned in your question, though _cover_ was, so I updated my answer

Comment: Is there something missing in my answer I can add or adjust, for you to accept?

Answer (score 2):

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('table tr td').on('click', function() {
        $('table tr td').removeClass('selected');
        var _index = $(this).index();
        $('table tr').each(function(index) {
            if (index > 0) { // all but not header
                $(this).find('td').each(function() {
                    if ($(this).index() < _index) {
                        $(this).addClass('selected');
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    });

});
```

Something like this?

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 
 $('table tr td').on('click', function(){
  $('table tr td').removeClass('selected');
  var _index = $(this).index();
  $('table tr').each(function(index){
   if (index>0) { // all but not header
    $(this).find('td').each(function(){
     if ($(this).index() < _index) {
      $(this).addClass('selected');
     }
    });
   }
  });
 });

});
```

```css
td {
 border: solid 1px #000;
}

td.selected {
 color:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
 <tr>
  <td>c1</td>
  <td>c2</td>
  <td>c3</td>
  <td>c4</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>d1</td>
  <td>d2</td>
  <td>d3</td>
  <td>d4</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>d1</td>
  <td>d2</td>
  <td>d3</td>
  <td>d4</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>d1</td>
  <td>d2</td>
  <td>d3</td>
  <td>d4</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>d1</td>
  <td>d2</td>
  <td>d3</td>
  <td>d4</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>d1</td>
  <td>d2</td>
  <td>d3</td>
  <td>d4</td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: not really : I want to show something over the cells hiding them , like an object having a higher z-index and having a dark background and a semitransparent opacity.

Comment: You can play with the class of selected items, black background color and a dark gray text, more simple of the js code part :)

Answer (score 1):

Updated based on a comment

Instead of looping through a lot of elements, add a class to the table itself, with an index value, and then you can easily set up a few CSS rules which takes care of the styling.

With that you could then use a pseudo to cover each cell, like this

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('table').on('click', function(e) {
    $(this).attr('class', 'idx' + $(e.target.parentElement).children().index(e.target));
  });
});
```

```css
td {
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid gray;
}

table.idx0 td:nth-child(-n+0)::after,
table.idx1 td:nth-child(-n+1)::after,
table.idx2 td:nth-child(-n+2)::after,
table.idx3 td:nth-child(-n+3)::after,
table.idx4 td:nth-child(-n+4)::after,
table.idx5 td:nth-child(-n+5)::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: -2px;                              /* 2px to make up for border/padding */
  top: -2px;
  height: calc(100% + 4px);
  width: calc(100% + 4px);
  background: black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>c1</th>
    <th>c2</th>
    <th>c3</th>
    <th>c4</th>
    <th>c5</th>
    <th>c6</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>d1</td>
    <td>d2</td>
    <td>d3</td>
    <td>d4</td>
    <td>d5</td>
    <td>d6</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>d1</td>
    <td>d2</td>
    <td>d3</td>
    <td>d4</td>
    <td>d5</td>
    <td>d6</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>d1</td>
    <td>d2</td>
    <td>d3</td>
    <td>d4</td>
    <td>d5</td>
    <td>d6</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Or simply set both color and background the same

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('table').on('click', function(e) {
    $(this).attr('class', 'idx' + $(e.target.parentElement).children().index(e.target));
  });
});
```

```css
td {
  border: 1px solid gray;
}

table.idx0 td:nth-child(-n+0),
table.idx1 td:nth-child(-n+1),
table.idx2 td:nth-child(-n+2),
table.idx3 td:nth-child(-n+3),
table.idx4 td:nth-child(-n+4),
table.idx5 td:nth-child(-n+5) {
  background: black;
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>c1</th>
    <th>c2</th>
    <th>c3</th>
    <th>c4</th>
    <th>c5</th>
    <th>c6</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>d1</td>
    <td>d2</td>
    <td>d3</td>
    <td>d4</td>
    <td>d5</td>
    <td>d6</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>d1</td>
    <td>d2</td>
    <td>d3</td>
    <td>d4</td>
    <td>d5</td>
    <td>d6</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>d1</td>
    <td>d2</td>
    <td>d3</td>
    <td>d4</td>
    <td>d5</td>
    <td>d6</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```